# how can i direct a port to alias on apache

Tags: docker, apache, proxy, webserver

i installed docker on my laptop and i have trouble remembering every port open by docker. so I want to point it to an alias on apache.
example:

i am running a web app in docker with port 8082 i want to access it via
http://localhost/myapp
without using the port.

this my httpd.conf

```
DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs"
<Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Includes

    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted


    alias /myapp
    ProxyPassMatch ^/myapp !
    ProxyPass /myapp http://localhost:9000/
    ProxyPassReverse /myapp http://localhost:9000/
    
</Directory>
```

how can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

Browsers communicate over port 80 by default for http and 443 for https. If you want to be able to access your application from localhost without explicitly stating the port, you can bind the container port to a host port when using docker run.
Example:

```sh
# -p HOST:CONTAINER
docker run -p 80:9000 <my_image>
```

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish-or-expose-port--p---expose

Comment: not like that.
what I want is when I access port 80 http://localhost/myapp it is automatically proxyed to port 9000 http://localhost:9000